# What is the purpose of raising more ETH for a DAO than can be invested in quality projects?

Tags: dapp-development, dao

I understand that DAO members can request ETH to be refunded before a proposal is accepted but what is the point in so much capital being raised? If I add up the sum of capital likely needed by the top 10 or 20 DAPPs I cannot reach the sum that has already been raised by the DAO.